# JMeter, pausing one HTTP call while allowing the others to continue

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to write a JMeter script and there's a problem with authentication. The token expires every 15 minutes, so I need to make a call to the login every 15 minutes. Is there a way to do this without halting the execution of the other calls?

[image]

I tried using a Constant Timer to delay the call to login, but it ends up keeping the other calls from proceeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is moving the `Login` request into a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

The token can be passed to the `API Call` Thread Group in 2 ways:

1. Via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the `Login` Thread Group, the property can be read in the `API Call` Thread Group by [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
2. Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

You may call the login only when your token is expired.
When the token is expired the API call will fail.

**Quick solution**
Just right-click the `API Call` HTTP request and Click insert parent and select while controller. Just put `LAST` in the condition. It will iterate till the sampler failure. When the sample fails it will start the next loop of the thread group and Login will get called. Also, it will not enter into the API Call if the login fails.

[image]

There could be many other solutions.